# 複数のディレクトリにファイルを一括コピーする方法。

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

カレントディレクトリ内にあるdirectory1からdirectory10までカレントディレクトリにあるファイルfileを一括コピーしたいです。どのようなコマンドを使えばいいでしょうか？現在は、一つずつcpコマンドしてmvで動かしているのでとても効率がわるいです。

【補足】
今現在C言語をやっています。
それぞれのフォルダーには関数がかかれたファイルが入っています。
たとえばカレントに以下のディレクトリがあります。
func_dir1 func_dir2 ...

そして、そのフォルダにはそれぞれfunctionXX（XX数字が入る）というファイルが入っています。

そしてそのfunctionのファイルには、関数が書かれています。
それらを実行するためには、main.c内で実行します。
そのためのmain.cを一気に作成したかったということです。

ファイルの例は、こんな感じです。

```
./func_dir1/function1


#include <stdio.h>

void function1(int a)
{
    int *n = &a;
    printf("%d", *n);
}
```

このようなファイルがそれぞれのディレクトリに入っています。
そして、以下のようなmain.cをそれぞれのフォルダーいかにまとめてつくりたいです。

```
int main(void)
{
    
}
```

なので、コピー以外でもいいのですが、すべてターミナルから操作しないといけません。

Comment: 質問の記述では、元がどんなフォルダ＆ファイル構成でコピー結果はどうなっているのか、またcpしてmv(なぜmv?)するという操作の詳細がいまいち分からないです。何かファイル名等によってコピー先を変えるとか？ 追記してみてください。

Comment: 一括で１つのファイルを複数のディレクトリにコピーするコマンドはありません。1つずつファイルをコピーするコマンドを１０回（１０種類）実行してください。
directory1からdirectory10までというのが、カレントディレクトリに存在するディレクトリの全てであるなら、カレントディレクトリに含まれるディレクトリのリストを取得して、ループで使うと見通しのよいコードになります。
ファイルとディレクトリの構成を説明せずに、プログラムが作れるなんて考えているとしたら、それは誤解ですよ。

Comment: zshであれば `cp -r directory{1..10} target_directory` で連番を生成して、コピーできますが、おそらくこれでは、内部のファイルだけではなくて、ディレクトリも持っていかれるから、ファイルを mv で移動させてるということでしょうか？　このままだと、推測で答えてしまうことになるので、みなさんのおっしゃる通り、ファイル構成ややりたいことを明確にする必要がありそうです。（そもそもLinuxにおいてディレクトリも広い意味でファイルではありますが、おそらく`ファイルfile`と表現されていることから、内部のディレクトリ、そしてdirectory1~ directory10自体は持っていきなくない？）

Comment: @sapcal000 さん。質問の編集ありがとうございます。もしかしたら、Makefileの方がやりたいことに近いかもしれない可能性がありそうですね。

Comment: @sapcal000さん 私は回答できるほどMakefileに詳しくないですが、再現できる最小限のコードとフォルダ構成（2つのディレクトリと複数のC言語ファイルでできると思います）があれば、C言語のエキスパートが回答しやすそうな印象です。

Comment: tee コマンドを使って、`echo $'int main(void)\n{\n\n}\n' | tee func_dir{1..10}/main.c > /dev/null` など。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

更新された質問文を見てもいまいち意図を掴みきれていない可能性があるのですが、
一応質問文の内容に基づいて回答します。(やりたいことと違うのであればコメントください。)

カレントディレクトリをdirectory(数字)のあるディレクトリにして、
カレントディレクトリにあるmain.cをdirectory(数字)に一括コピーするには次のようにします。

```
$ find . -type d -name directory\* | xargs -n1 cp -p main.c
```

以下実行結果です。

```
$ ls -lA
合計 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 main.c

$ seq 1 10 | xargs -I@ mkdir directory@
$ ls -lA
合計 44
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory1
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory10
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory2
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory3
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory4
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory5
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory6
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory7
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory8
drwxrwxr-x 2 hidezzz hidezzz 4096  8月 10 12:33 directory9
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz   25  8月 10 12:28 main.c

$ find . -type d -name directory\* | xargs -n1 cp -p main.c
$ ls -lA directory*/*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory1/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory10/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory2/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory3/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory4/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory5/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory6/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory7/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory8/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 25  8月 10 12:28 directory9/main.c
```